# editing the counting of section

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I've found this .cls template on the web and modified it a little bit (I deleted the title page part, otherwise my post would be to long):

```
%% 
%% This file is part of the LaTeX2e system. 
%% ---------------------------------------- 
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{thesis}[2009/01/06 Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute]
%  Note that the setspace package is built in (code included near the end of 
%  this file) to provide "line-and-a half spacing" (1.4 by default) and also
%  the singlespace environment. 

% RPI option chap:
\newif\ifchap  % true for chap option
  \chapfalse   % false by default
\DeclareOption{chap}{\chaptrue} % option to print "Chapter" at each new chapter
\newcommand\docsize{}  % to allow 10pt or 11pt to be specified as option
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\docsize{12pt}}
%  Prepare to load the standard report class (12pt):
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ExecuteOptions{12pt}         % define 12pt as the default doc size
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[\docsize]{report}  % load report.cls
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%  The following sections are revisions or additions to report.cls
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  FOOTNOTES:   make them continuously numbered throughout document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% define command that can undo having footnotes reset with each chapter:
% (taken from removefr.sty by Donald Arseneau) 
\def\@removefromreset#1#2{\let\@tempb\@elt
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\@tempa\csname c@#1\endcsname
   \def\@elt##1{\expandafter\ifx\csname c@##1\endcsname\@tempa\else
         \noexpand\@elt{##1}\fi}%
   \expandafter\edef\csname cl@#2\endcsname{\csname cl@#2\endcsname}%
   \let\@elt\@tempb}
% use the command \@removefromreset to undo the \@addtoreset in report.cls:
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
%
% define command to allow people to reset footnote counter at will: 
\def\resetfootnote{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}  % definition to reset footnote


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE LAYOUT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SIDE MARGINS:
\if@twoside                 % Values for two-sided printing:
   \oddsidemargin .55in     %   Left margin on odd-numbered pages.
   \evensidemargin .05in    %   Left margin on even-numbered pages.
   \marginparwidth 40pt     %   Width of marginal notes.
\else                       % Values for one-sided printing:
   \oddsidemargin 0.55in    %   Note that \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
   \evensidemargin 0.55in
   \marginparwidth 40pt
\fi
\marginparsep 10pt          % Horizontal space between outer margin and
                            % marginal note
\textwidth 5.9in            % width of text

% VERTICAL SPACING:
                         % Top of page:
\topmargin -.5in         %    distance from top of page to running head
\headheight 14pt         %    Height of box containing running head.
\headsep .4in            %    Space between running head and text.
\textheight 8.8in        %    space for text
\footskip 30pt           %    Distance from baseline of box containing foot
                         %    to baseline of last line of text.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                            SECTION HEADINGS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\newcommand\chaptersize{\large}
\newcommand\sectionsize{\large}
\newcommand\subsectionsize{\normalsize}
\newcommand\subsubsectionsize{\normalsize}
\newcounter{firstchapter}
\setcounter{firstchapter}{0}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}    % Number subsubsections in the chapters
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}       % Put subsubsections in the table of contents

% Print "CHAPTER" if chap option is specified:
\ifchap
  \renewcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}
\else
  \renewcommand\@chapapp{}
\fi

\def\specialhead#1{%   GENERAL HEADING WITHOUT A NUMBER (for abstract, etc.)
     \ifx\phantomsection\undefined
     \else
        \clearpage\phantomsection
     \fi
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
     \chapter*{\centering #1 \@mkboth{#1}{#1}}}


\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum\c@firstchapter=0    % start of rpi added stuff
                      \if@twoside\cleardoublepage\suppressfloats[t]\fi
                      \pagenumbering{arabic} 
                      \setcounter{firstchapter}{1}
                    \fi
                    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
                    \thispagestyle{plain}
                    \pagestyle{myheadings}      % end of rpi added stuff
                    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter.}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}% 
%                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
%                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering \normalfont \chaptersize
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \ifchap
         \bfseries \@chapapp{} \thechapter    % print "Chapter" and number
         \vskip -3pt           %\par\nobreak (original)
       \else
         \bfseries \thechapter. 
       \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 15\p@
  }}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%    heading for chapter* command (no numbering)
  \vspace*{0\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \centering
    \normalfont  \chaptersize 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 15\p@
  }}

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {.5ex \@plus .3ex}%{1.4ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\sectionsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {3.25ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {.3ex \@plus .2ex}%{1.2ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\subsectionsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {3.25ex\@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                     {.2ex \@plus .1ex}%{1ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\subsubsectionsize\bfseries}}
% \paragraph and \subparagraph headings unchanged from report.cls.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  APPENDIX
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \chaptrue
  \renewcommand\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  FIGURES and TABLES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%control float placement:
%
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.8}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\bottomfraction{.8}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{.8}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{2}
\renewcommand\dbltopfraction{.8}
\renewcommand\dblfloatpagefraction{.8}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\bfseries#1:~~#2}%   Make caption bold
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
   {\bfseries #1:~~#2}\par%            Make caption bold
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  TABLE of CONTENTS,  LIST OF TABLES,  LIST OF FIGURES 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \vskip -1em \begin{singlespace}      % singlespacing
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \end{singlespace}
    }

\renewcommand*\l@chapter{\pagebreak[3]\vskip 10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
                         \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\vskip 6pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
                         \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\ifnum\c@tocdepth>1\vskip 4pt minus 1pt \fi
                         \@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\ifnum\c@tocdepth>2 \vskip 3pt minus 1pt \fi
                         \@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}

% The following removed because it's not consistent with entries from longtable
%% modify the definition below (taken from latex.ltx) to include 
%% "Table" and "Figure" in entries for lot and lof: 
%\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%\baselineskip 14.5 pt
%  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
%  {\protect\numberline{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
%  \begingroup
%    \@parboxrestore
%    \normalsize
%    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
%  \endgroup}

\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \ifx\phantomsection\undefined
      \else
        \clearpage\phantomsection
      \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}  % add lof to toc
    \chapter*{\centering\listfigurename  % center it
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}%
    \vskip -1em \begin{singlespace}  % singlespacing
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \end{singlespace}
    }

\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \ifx\phantomsection\undefined
      \else
        \clearpage\phantomsection
      \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}  % add lot to toc
    \chapter*{\centering\listtablename  % center it
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}%
        \vskip -1em \begin{singlespace}  % singlespacing
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \end{singlespace}
    }

%remove following at same time as remove code to put "Figure" in LOF
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\vskip 10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
%                       \@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5.8em}}

\renewcommand*\l@figure{\vskip 10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
                       \@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.8em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure

\let\rpicaption\caption
\let\lrpicaption\caption


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  BIBLIOGRAPHY
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% RPI def: for use in making an unnumbered bibliography with hanging indents
\def\bibentry{\vskip10pt\par\noindent\hangindent=40pt\frenchspacing}

% report definition modified for no automatic heading and use ragged right
\newcommand{\bibalign}{\raggedright}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\bibalign\frenchspacing
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.=\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SOME INITIALIZATIONS:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% make the following names uppercase:
\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand\bibname{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\renewcommand\indexname{INDEX}
\renewcommand\partname{PART}
\renewcommand\chaptername{CHAPTER}
\renewcommand\appendixname{APPENDIX}
\renewcommand\abstractname{ABSTRACT}

\renewcommand\chaptersize{\large}
\renewcommand\sectionsize{\large}
\renewcommand\subsectionsize{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionsize{\normalsize}

\raggedbottom

\setstretch{1.4}        % at 11 or 12pt this is line-and-a-half spacing
\parindent .4in         % Width of paragraph indentation

\markboth{}{}           % Do not include chapter titles in headers;
\pagestyle{myheadings}  % include just page numbers in upper right

\renewcommand{\bibalign}{\raggedright}  %  bibliography is ragged right
% for fully justified bibliography: \renewcommand{\bibalign}{}

\endinput
%% 
%% End of file `thesis.cls'.
```

The problem is the following: The numbering of the theorem is like this: 1.0.3, where 1 (chapter). 0 (section) 3.(the number of the object in this section). I would like to modify the .cls template in such a way, that section starts counting at 1 instead of 0. How could I fix this, which means what do I have to change in this template? Thanks for your help

math

Comment: The section counter is incremented by the `\section` command. If you increment the counter manualy with `\stepcounter{section}` before the first section header then you first section will be numberd 2. The answer is to put a section header before your first theorem. The zero you see is correct because there are no section header yet,

Comment: It would be helpful if you augmented your posting with a MWE that generates the unwanted behavior. From your description alone, it would appear that you have a `\chapter` statement and later a `\subsubsection` statement, but no intermediate `\subsection` statement. If that's the case, there's nothing wrong with the class file you're working with.

Comment: Thanks you both for your comments. Sorry if my questions was not that clear. My first chapter is the Introduction. There I do not want to subdivide it into different sections. But I also want that a Theorem is stated like: Theorem 1.1.1 instead of Theorem 1.0.1

Comment: So you just need to put `\stepcounter{section}` immediately after `\chapter{Introduction}`, and likewise for any other chapters that are not divided into sections. It's a bit odd to have theorems in the introduction, though!

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a theorem number of 1.1.1, 1.1.2, etc in a chapter without sections it can be very confusing. I recommend that you reset the theorem counter to a lower level for such chapter, e.g. 1.1, 1.2, etc.

I cannot see where the theorem definition is but assume it is with the `amsthm` package. See code below

*Edit 1:* Move `\setthmtochp` and `\setthmtosec` before `\chapter` commands

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{remreset}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand\thethm{\thesection.\arabic{thm}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setthmtochp{%
    \@removefromreset{thm}{chapter}% just in case ... (no harm done)
    \@removefromreset{thm}{section}%
    \@addtoreset{thm}{chapter}%
    \renewcommand\thethm{\thechapter.\arabic{thm}}}
\newcommand\setthmtosec{%
    \@removefromreset{thm}{chapter}%
    \@removefromreset{thm}{section}% just in case ... (no harm done)
    \@addtoreset{thm}{section}%
    \renewcommand\thethm{\thesection.\arabic{thm}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setthmtochp%--Edit 1
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}

\setthmtosec%--Edit 1
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{A section}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}

\section{A section}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}
\begin{thm}[The title]Some statements ... \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I see that `\@removefromreset` is already defined in your class and you may not need the `remreset` package.

Comment: @math: Please see changes where `\setthmtochp` and `\setthmtosec` was moved to be before \chapter commands